# Compute factorials efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, combinations

I have an array with `N` upto 10^5.
I need to solve `Q` range queries with given `L` and `R`.
`Q` <= 10^5

For each query, I need to find distinct elements in range L to R
and then find their factorial.

For example, if array is `{5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7}`.

If `L = 2` and `R = 4`.

Then we  have `{ 4 : 2 times, 2: 1 time }`, so answer is `(2!)*(1!) = 2`.

If `L = 1` and `R = 5`
Then we have `{5 : 2 times, 4: 2 times, 2 : 1 time}`, so answer is `(2!)*(2!).(1!) = 4` .

`O((N)*(Q))` solution to this problem is obvious.
How can I optimize it.

NOTE: All factorials are calculated modulo 1000000007

Comment: Is 10^5 the max *size* of the array or the max element *value?*

Comment: @paxdiablo 10^5 is max size of array. elements can be upto 10^9

Comment: "All factorials are calculated modulo 1000000007" Is this a programming competition? If so, please post a link. If the competition is still ongoing, please refrain from asking and answering questions about it

Answer (score 3):

Okay, since (as per your comment), there can only be 10<sup>5</sup> elements in the array, that's also the maximum *count* of each possible value in the array.

So one thing you could do would be to pre-calculate all those factorials into an array and use those for the calculations.

Probably the best way to do this is to write a meta-program which constructs the values into a C++ structure that you can then include in your own code<sup>(a)</sup>. The structure would look something like:

```
unsigned int facMod10p7[] = {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    :
    /* whatever (10^5)! % 1000000007 is */
};
```

Once you have that, the lookup of each factorial is O(1). To do the query side of things, you simply iterate over the array (from `L` to `R`) counting the number of unique values.

This is probably best done with a `map<unsigned int, unsigned int>` with the first field being the value (assuming unsigned values here but you could just as easily make this signed) and the second being the number of times it occurred.

For the `L2/R4` case of `{4, 2, 4}`, you would end up with a map thus:

```
{ [2] = 1, [4] = 2 }
```

Then it's a simple matter of iterating over that looking up the factorial for each count and taking the product of them all.

Since it's an O(1) lookup/multiplication within an O(n) loop, the resulting complexity would be O(n).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For example, a Python program to output the first 10,000 factorials takes about 30 seconds on my box to generate the entire table (in my WSL environment, not necessarily known for its blinding I/O speed, at least until the next release due soon):

```
real 0m29.137s
user 0m28.438s
sys  0m0.547s
```

The code, if you want to do your own tests, is:

```
print('static unsigned int facMod10p7[] = {\n    0,')
val = 1
mult = 2
for i in range(100000):
    print('    {},'.format(val) % 1000000007)
    val *= mult
    mult += 1
print(');')
```

Comment: what about queries in array, please see examples. answer to a query is the  product of factorials of count of distinct elements in a range.

Comment: (10^5)! has something like 456574 digits. Yikes.

Comment: @ggorlen: `(10^5)! % 1000000007` has, at most, ten digits :-) In any case, these only need to be calculated *once* and the resulting structure included in your code. This would be a doddle using MPIR, for example.

Comment: @paxdiablo this will result in complexity of O((N^2)*(Q))

Comment: @alex, where is the quadratic term coming from in your proposed complexity? You count the elements in the range with O(n), the factorial lookups and multiplications are now O(1). That's a result of O(n).

Comment: @ggorlen, calculating all those factorials is an irrelevant cost if you're only doing it once. Not once per run of the program but *once per entire history of the universe* :-) And, based on how I've seen MPIR perform with integers, I'd suggest it wouldn't be much of an effort.

Comment: Yeah, if it's in the spirit of the challenge to use a library, then it's no problem. I can't think of any tricks offhand...

Comment: @paxdiablo Ah its O(QN), which is 10^10 computations, it would best pass testcases in O(NlogN) :(

Comment: @alex (and ggorlen), I've added some Python code (and timings) to show that the cost of pre-generation is not that onerous.

Comment: @paxdiablo heh you neat me by 40 mins :) have not seen your answer until now ... I agree this is linear not quadratic ...

Comment: @alex you got error in your second example 5 is in the array 3 times ...

Comment: Do you know how big 100000! is?

Comment: @n.m., it's about 450,000 digits long. But, as the question states, this is only important during generation of the table (and it's not that onerous, as my timings show). The table itself is modulo(10^9ish).

Comment: @Spektre, I'm not convinced alex actually *has* an error in the second example. With L=1/R=5, that's only the first five elements of the array, which is `5, 4, 2, 4, 5`. As indicated by the first example, array element 0 is `L=1`, since `L=2/R=4` gives `4, 2, 4`.

Comment: "All factorials are calculated modulo 1000000007" Is this a programming competition? If so, please post a link. If the competition is still ongoing, please refrain from asking and answering questions about it.

Comment: @n.m., you should probably direct that comment at the question rather than the answer. If the question is somehow invalid, it should be deleted (taking the answers with it) but people (well, at least me) will just answer questions as asked, since I make few assumptions about its validity, other than the quality itself, of course.

Comment: @paxdiablo you right, I'm just not paying attention.

Comment: @paxdiablo hmm I taught the `L,R` range was applied on the values of the array not on index in array ... If not the case you're right ... its a bit ambitious as in OP there is none description about this ...

Answer (score 3):

Lets consider your example:

```
n = 7
A[n] = {5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7}
L = 2
R = 4
p = 1000000007
```

1. **compute histogram `H[]` of `A[]` which is  `O(n)`**

   of all the values in the array of size `n` which are in between `L,R` where `m` is max count of any of your value.

   ```
    H[2] = 1
    H[3] = 0
    H[4] = 2
   ```

   in code something like:

   ```cpp
   int H[R-L+1],i;
   for (i=L,i<=R;i++) H[i-L]=0;
   for (i=0,i<n;i++)
    if ((A[i]>=L)&&(A[i]<=R)
     H[i-L]++;
   ```

   I shifted the `H` index by L so we are not wasting space so:

   ```
    H[0] = 1
    H[1] = 0
    H[2] = 2
   ```
2. **find `m = max(H[])` which is `O(R-L+1)`**

   simply:

   ```cpp
   int m;
   for (m=H[0],i=L+1;i<=R;i++)
    if (m<H[i-L])
     m=H[i-L];
   ```

   so:

   ```
   m = 2
   ```
3. **precompute all factorials up to `m` which is  `O(m)`**

   ```cpp
   int F[m+1],j;
   j=1; F[0]=j;
   for (i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
    j=modmul(j,i,p); // j = j*i mod p
    F[i]=j;
    }
   ```

   so:

   ```
   F[] = { 0!,1!,2! }
   F[] = { 0 ,1 ,2  }
   ```
4. **compute the final PI of factorials which is O(R-L+1)**

   so simply:

   ```cpp
   for (j=1,i=L;i<=R;i++)
    j=modmul(j,F[H[i-L]],p);
   // here j is your result
   ```

   so:

   ```
   j = F[H[0]]*F[H[1]]*F[H[2]] 
   j = F[1]*F[0]*F[2] 
   j = 1!*0!*2! 
   j = 2
   ```

As you can see the whole process is `O(n+m+R-L)` which is much much better than yours `O(N*Q)`

If you doing this operation a lot of times than you should consider to precompute `F[]` to your max `n` value ...

If I choose `L=1,R=5` then the stuff is like this:

```
//      1 2 3 4 5
H[] = { 0,1,0,2,3 }
m = 3
//      0 1 2 3
F[] = { 1,1,2,6 }
PI(F[H]) = F[0]*F[1]*F[0]*F[2]*F[3]
         =   1 *  1 *  1 *  2! * 3! 
         =   2*6
         =  12
```

You got bug in your histogram as 5 is in array 3 times not 2 !!! However if the range is applied on the index of array instead of its value then ist not a bug and my approach need a slight change in the indexes ... all `i` for cycles would be from `L` to `R` instead.